# Joomla Complicated URL Rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, sef

We are currently creating a new website for the purpose of including a shopping cart. The problem we have is that we currently rank well for all of our keywords on google and need to recreate our urls exactly as they are on our existing Joomla installation.

We have a business that is heavily reliant on our search traffic from google (we know this is not ideal!). The shopping cart we want to use is mijoshop (based on opencart)

Our current URL format is http://www.yahire.com/index.php/chair-hire/folding-chair-hire.html

The default url's for this shopping cart are awful and we can change these using an SEF plugin but this removes the index.php from all url's so they would be for example

http://www.yahire.com/chair-hire/folding-chair-hire

We planed to phase out the index.php gradually from the url starting with index.php/event-accessories then moving on to index.php/chair-hire so that if one section of our site drops in rank we still have traffic coming in from the other sections.

Does anybody know of a way to keep some pages containing the index.php/ and some without?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Have you thought about using the redirect extension in the core of joomla which will do permanent redirects.

Comment: I haven't, but i will take a look at that now and see if it can do it. Thanks for your suggestion. There was a whole list of suggestions yesterday which have now been deleted do you know why this would be?

Comment: This does not work with Mijoshop, the urls get re-written alright but the product will not show with the re-written URL